# Adding multiple products to an enquiry and the submitting once

Tags: forms, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am working on a website that has 200 products.

*It is NOT an e-commerce site so the user cannot purchase the products on the site.*

The idea that I am exploring is that the user can add multiple products to an "Enquiry Cart" and ask the question at the end, rather than submitting a form after every product.

I am not sure about the logic of this feature, and if anybody would actually use it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Zlatko!  The situation you describe makes sense.  However, your question is unclear. Are you wondering how to determine whether people would use the feature? Or how the feature should differ from a shopping cart? Or how to make sure people don't confuse the "enquiry cart" with the more common pattern of a shopping cart? Or something else altogether?

Comment: The question is, how do I determine if the feature is useful. I am having doubts if people will actually use the feature because users usually don't want to wait for information.

Comment: I don't why looking at cart paradigms would hurt, after all, the only difference really is that the user must enquire rather than actually pay, something they presumably know based on your business type / relationship with you / product type / sector etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to think about this UX without knowing what exactly you're selling, but in principle what you're describing works just fine.

For example, if you are selling a set of complex services which require an inquiry before sale, it's reasonable to enqueue a set of items for batch or package inquiry:

[image: murder]

This might work for other complex/packaged products like custom vacation packages, private jet service, etc.